# How to track custom variables in flutter using matomo plugin

Tags: flutter, matomo

Does flutter provide a way of tracking custom variables using Matomo plugin as we do in native development.

Answer (score 1):

Finally achieved this by creating method channel for android and writing matomo code in android specific project.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create custom dimention in Matomo using advance setting in measurable
2. Custom Dimentions

```
Map<String, String> customDim = {
  'dimension1': 'Id-123',
  'dimension2': 'Hardik', //firstName
  'dimension3': 'Singhal', //lastname
};
```

3. Matomo Event

```
MatomoTracker.instance.trackEvent(
  eventInfo: EventInfo(
    category: 'testCategory',
    name: '$eventName'.toLowerCase(),
    action: 'testAction'.toLowerCase(),
    value: 18,
  ),
  path: "/$eventName",
  pvId: "6charL",
  dimensions: customDim,
);
'''
```